chrome extension not working without opening the chrome console
I am currently developing a chrome extension to control Google Map. The code will input keyword to the search box and click it.
It works fine when I open the chrome console. But won't work if the console is closed.
The code snippet is in below :
async function searchwithkeyword (keyword){

    const searchbox_xpath = ".//div/div[3]/div[8]/div[3]/div/div/div/div[2]/form/input"
    const searchbox_btn_xpath = ".//div/div[3]/div[8]/div[3]/div/div/div/div[2]/div/button"

    const searchbox_element = document.evaluate(
        searchbox_xpath, 
        document, 
        null,
        XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE,
        null
    );
    const searchbox_btn_element = document.evaluate(
        searchbox_btn_xpath,
        document,
        null,
        XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE,
        null
    );
    
    
    const searchbox_entry = searchbox_element.singleNodeValue
    const searchbox_btn = searchbox_btn_element.singleNodeValue
        
    if (searchbox_entry && searchbox_btn){
        searchbox_entry.value = keyword
        searchbox_btn.click()
    } else {
        console.log("FAIL")
        return false
    }

    return new Promise ((resolve) => {  
        setTimeout (() => {resolve(true);}, 3000)
    });
}

Result : run extension with chrome console opened
Behave as expected
Result : run extension with chrome console closed
Seems that the searchbox_entry and searchbox_btn is not found

Assuming you run this code as a content script, which you should, you need to re-inject files from content_scripts after reloading/installing the extension in Chrome. Also, use devtools to inspect whether the element you want is inside an iframe, and if it is, add the necessary declarations.

Yeah I am running this code in content script, and I think I have injected the content script from the background.js as below
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener((tabId, changeInfo, tab) => {
if (changeInfo.status === 'complete' && tab.url && tab.url.includes('google.com/maps')) {
chrome.scripting.executeScript({
target: { tabId: tabId },
files: ['content.js']
});
}
});

Also, I have added the snap shot of the result. Please check it if it helps understand my questions. Thanks

Your script runs when the initial html has been processed, but this is a modern site that builds the page asynchronously using its scripts. You need to wait for the elements to appear by either polling with setInterval or via MutationObserver.
